# An easy way to run an ASP.Net application at home?

Tags: asp.net

I'd like to run some small private/home applications on a local machine, but I dislike the idea to set up a full Win2003 Server with IIS for this.

Is there a easy and cheap way to get an ASP.Net application running at home?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 2000 has ASP, Windows XP Professional also can run it.  Look up how to turn on IIS, the built in webserver.  Sure Win2k3 Server would be a nicer implementation, but for personal stuff, any of them work.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way, assuming your desktop has an OS that supports it, is the [Microsoft Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/channel/products/WebPlatformInstaller.aspx). Requires XP or higher, but doesn't work on Home editions of XP or Vista. It'll install IIS (which version depends on your OS), SQL Server 2008 Express, the .Net Framework, Visual Web Developer 2008 Express, ASP.NET MVC, Silverlight, and more. There's even a video on the linked page that'll show you how to set it all up.

Answer (score 1):

Try VIsual Studio 2008 Express Web Developer. It's free, and better than many that are not. It comes with a built-in web server so you can compile,deploy and test immediately. No need for IIS.

http://www.microsoft.com/express/vwd/

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what kind of app and what version of .Net you could run Cassini. It's the free, open source web server that supports .Net. I'm not sure if it's been updated to handle 3.5, but I used to use at home to run some pretty serioud 2.0 apps that I had written.

Here's the Ultidev version which has been updated: http://www.ultidev.com/products/Cassini/ Looks like it'll handle 3.5, so pretty much anything you have.

Answer (score 0):

I have been running .NET apps on my home machine (XP) for years, and ASP apps for years before that. Just install IIS and then the .NET frameworks (and whatever else you need, e.g., MVC) and you are good to go. If your machine is behind a router you will need to port-forward port 80 to your desktop. If you do not have static IP, you can use a free service like [DynDNS.org](http://DynDNS.org) to give you a hostname, and you run a small client to keep the DNS for that hostname pointed to your router's IP. If you want to use your own hostname, register one with someone like [GoDaddy.com](http://GoDaddy.com), and then use a free service like [ZoneEdit.com](http://ZoneEdit.com) to keep the DNS updated with the correct IP.